# Find a recurrence relation for the number of ternary strings that do not contain consecutive symbols that are the same.

Tags: recurrence-relations

I tried to solve this question by subtracting the number of strings that contain consecutive symbols that are same from the total number of symbols possible of length n.

Let b<sub>n</sub> denote the number of strings of length n, with consecutive symbols that are same. Then b<sub>n</sub> can be obtained by 3*b<sub>n-1</sub> , since there are 3 choices for appending the string of length n-1 to form a string of length n. So if a<sub>n</sub> denotes the number of strings of length n that do not contain consecutive symbols that are same then, a<sub>n</sub> = 3<sup>n</sup> - b<sub>n-1</sub> . But I am stuck, how do I go from here ? How to solve such problems without generating the sequence and guessing ? I am having a hard time doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Well, if $a_n$ denotes the number of ternary strings without consecutive symbols, and you are given such a string of length $n-1$, you can form an $n$-string by attaching $0,1,2$ at the end except you must make sure not to duplicate the last symbol. In other words you have 2 choices for the last character.

Can you finish this?

Comment: Yes, so a(n)= 2a(n-1) , that seems so obvious now, thanks.  Sometimes I make such simple things so complicated.

Comment: @srishti77714 this answer is correct :-)