# Number of possible strings of length $n$ without three consecutive repetitions

Tags: combinatorics

A sequence of $n$ characters, consisting of the characters $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$; how many sequences of length $n$ exist without three consecutive characters being identical?

This problem was part of a set of programming problems whose solutions were based on counting principles. 
Input: N
Output: number of strings corresponding to above condition

To simplify the output, we were required to give the result modulo some specifc number as the output, but that's probably an irrelevant detail.

My first thought was inclusion-exclusion, but I couldn't figure out the solution. Can anyone provide any insight?

Example:
Input:
N = 3
Output: 
Count = 60
Justification:
4^3 - {$AAA$, $BBB$, $CCC$, $DDD$}
= 64 - 4 = 60

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a recurrence relation for the number of ternary strings that do not contain consecutive symbols that are the same.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950538/find-a-recurrence-relation-for-the-number-of-ternary-strings-that-do-not-contain)

Comment: Tbh, I've no idea how to solve recurrence relations, I'll get on that. But, I was hoping to get an answer via counting principles (which I'm just assuming recurrence relations are not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $T_n$ is the amount of such sequences of length $n$, $$T_n=3\left(T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}\right),$$ for $n\geq3$.

Comment: I cant really wrap my head about this, but I also know nothing about recurrence relations, I'll read up on it and then attempt this route; thank you! But any help regarding an approach using inclusion-exclusiom or something like that

Comment: I’ll give another hint. Any valid string of length at least $3$ is composed of a shorter valid string, with one of $3$ characters at the end, either once or twice. Can you see where this is going now?

Comment: I think so: you mean that we can create a valid string out of valid substrings by selecting a character that is not the terminating character of the substring, and append it either once or twice; since there are only three options for the appended character, u added the coefficient 3. Is that right?

Comment: So, 3[T(n-1)] is the subset of Tn where a single character is added, and 3[T(n-2)] the subset to which two identical characters were added?

Comment: So then it would follow that I find some formula for Tn in terms of n using initial conditions T1 = 4, T2 = 16?

Comment: @Numi Yep, precisely so.

Comment: Many thanks, after reading the theory regarding linear, I've gotten to the step of creating the characteristic equation. My roots are irrational, but I suppose once expanded out it will become an integer. I have a last follow up question regarding the final solution: my equation is now Tn = C((3+[sqrt(21)])/2)^(n-1) + D(same term except minus sqrt(21)). Is it valid for me to sub in T0 = 0?

Comment: @Numi Your value $T_0$ would be such that $T_2=3\left(T_0+T_1\right)$, but the argument that got us our recursion isn’t valid for $n\leq2$. So, plugging in wouldn’t be valid. You can, however, calculate it directly: the only string of length zero is the empty string, which does satisfy your condition. Therefore, $T_0=1$.